# Windows keeps muting all sounds when detecting communication

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, headphones, discord

Whenever I join discord voice call, Windows keps muting all my sounds.

**I did set it, so Windows does nothing when there is communication active**, however it doesn't work and all results on the internet mention this setting as a solution.

I noticed that right-clicking sound and turning ON and OFF the *Spatial Sound: Windows Sonic for headphones* was a workaround for me. Unfortunately after latest windows/sound drivers update it stopped working.

How do I permanently fix that problem?

I am using SteelSeries Arctis 7 headphones with two audio devices and Windows 10 21H1.

**UPDATE**:
Turns out is wasn't muting all sounds, but audio was present only on second channel: Chat
Other troubleshooting I did was:

- reinstalled audio drivers, discord, SteelSeries GG app and Engine, updated windows
- set Game channel as default device and Chat channel as default communications device
- disabled "exclusive control" and spatial sound for both
- set SteelSeries Arctis 7 Certified as audio devices in Discord

Comment: If you have more than one audio device, you may need to set this setting that you bolded for more than one devices too. Keep in mind that you can have separate input devices and output devices too.

Comment: That setting is for system and not for each device.

Comment: I just discovered that when connecting to discord, all sounds go from *game audio* to *chat audio*. Setting *chat* as main audio output allows to hear them with low quality, but going back to *game* fixes the problem (until reconnecting on discord). I will investigate it later and update question/answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So uhm, apparently the root of this problem was plugging the receiver into USB hub. Even USB-C port isn't enough to avoid problems.

A short explanation that I received was, that some devices don't like how usb hubs merge the data and power lines between ports